# vscode databaseclient sqlite3 is not installed!

Tags: база-данных, sqlite, visual-studio-code

Я пытаюсь использовать расширение Database Client но кнопка для скачки sqlite3 не работает испробовал очень огромное количество разных вариантов, подскажите пожалуйста как избежать данную проблему
[image: Код ошибки]

Answer (score 0):

Для windows. В систему не установлен sqlite или его нет в Path. Надо скачать архив sqlite-tools-win-x64 с сайта https://sqlite.org/download.html, распаковать и добавить папку с распакованным архивом в Path. После перезагрузки VSCode должно заработать.